# Combining probabilities for overlapping regions

Tags: probability, geostatistics

For two regions which have independent probabilities of an event happening and share an overlapping region, what is the probability of an event happening in the combined region? I'm speaking of physical space here, not abstract set intersections.

For instance, if I am given one region that has a 40% probability of an event happening there, and another that has a 15% probability of the same type of event, what is the probability in the intersecting region? We can assume that the probabilities are independent of one another. This could apply to counties overlapping with census tracts, arbitrary geographical shapes, etc.

Here's an image to visualize what I'm looking for:

[image: overlapping regions with independent probabilities]

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, so I am putting this in comments. And sorry I am three years late. I think the combined probability for either P1 _or_ P2 is: 1 - ((1-P1)*(1-P2)) which equals 0.49. The probability in the ? region for _both_ P1 and P2 is P1*P2 = 0.06. Warning: I DO NOT KNOW FOR SURE. I found this while looking for answers to the very question you are asking. I am surprised no one has answered it already.

Comment: There's no way to tell: all you can say is that the answer lies between 0% and 15%. In the first instance, no events can possibly occur in the intersection; in the second instance, all the events within the 15% region are also in the 40% region.  Both circumstances are consistent with the information provided.

Comment: @whuber Perhaps the OP will change the question in response to your comment, but otherwise I think your comment actually gives the full solution set for the problem. Perhaps give it some time, but consider posting it as an answer later.

Comment: "*I'm speaking of physical space here, not abstract set intersections.*" Okay, so how would you otherwise model the notion of this overlap without using set intersections? We're talking about modelling, I assume, so some amount of abstraction is necessary.

Comment: @Galen The language strongly implies a spatial point process.  For each subset $\mathcal A,$ the random variable $N(\mathcal A)$ is the number of events occurring within $\mathcal A.$  The chance that an event occurs is $\Pr(N(\mathcal A)\gt 0).$  That's as far as one can go without further assumptions.  The archetypical example is a homogeneous Poisson process in which $N(\mathcal A)$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter proportional to the area of $\mathcal A$ and $N(\mathcal B),N(\mathcal A)$ are independent *iff* $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are two $\textit{independent events}$, the probability of both events happening together is simply
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B).$$

Since $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B) = 0.15$, $P(A\cap B)$ = $0.4 \cdot 0.15$ = $0.06$.

That is the probability of an event happening in the combined region is $6\%$. Hope this will help.

Comment: Although you are correct about events, what makes this question a little different from others is its spatial aspect.  It looks like it's really asking about a spatial point process.  (The [tag:geostatistics] tag is a very strong hint.) An answer can be developed only by making an assumption about that process; for instance, whether it is homogeneous.

Comment: @whuber What is it about the geostatistics tag that indicates a spatial point process? The wording and diagram in the original question seems to point (very strongly in my opinion) to such a description of probabilities on bounded regions of space...

Comment: @Galen Probabilities of what, exactly?  //  Look at any standard geostats text, such as Cressie's original book.  It will cover various kinds of spatial processes, including point processes.  That's one reason [tag:geostatistics] indicates the question is about spatial processes, *not* about subsets of space as if they were "events" in some sigma algebra.

Comment: @whuber Probabilities, when mathematically formalized in Probability Theory, are always elements of the image of a probability measure on some event space of a sigma algebra. This includes point processes, although for every point in space you can have a distinct probability measure and consequently a distinct probability for a given event. However, looking at [Cressie & Moore 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07216) I can see the emphasis you are referring to. I think it is best to close the question as requiring details or clarity, as you have.